# No loader is configured for .vue files: error on nuxt 3 project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, jspdf, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 project and installed the js pdf package to generate the PDF `vue3-simple-html2pdf` [package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-simple-html2pdf).

Also, I have created one plugin file to use that plugin

**plugins/js-pdf.js**

```js
import Vue3SimpleHtml2pdf from "vue3-simple-html2pdf";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3SimpleHtml2pdf);
});
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: false,
    plugins: ['~/plugins/js-pdf'],
    css: ["assets/css/main.css"],
})
```

I found the error `No loader is configured for ".vue" files: node_modules/vue3-simple-html2pdf/src/vue3-simple-html2pdf.vue`

Kindly please help me with this and do let me know if anything is required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the package itself. If you go to `/node_modules/vue3-simple-html2pdf/src/index.js` you will see this line:

```js
import Vue3SimpleHtml2pdf from 'vue3-simple-html2pdf/src/vue3-simple-html2pdf'
```

add a .vue to the end.

```js
import Vue3SimpleHtml2pdf from 'vue3-simple-html2pdf/src/vue3-simple-html2pdf.vue'
```

This is problematic though (if you update or download it onto a different device...). You should ask the package creator to do it.

Comment: You could try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-resolve-extension-vue

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is the right way to add this specific package to hide this issue? OR if you have any idea about any other plugin for downloading and generate pdf (I am using nuxt 3) then please help me with this

Comment: By the way, I just tried to add this plugin but still it returns the same error. Can you please help me to fix this way or please suggest way you know

Comment: Have you tried actually editing the package source file to see if it works? If it does you could perhaps flag my answer as correct. Btw, I made a pull request on the package github repo so it should get into it as soon as the owner accepts this small change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have checked this to change the main package file but its no work for me!